# Corrupted /mnt/obb mount point?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I was testing mounting and reading data from a **.obb** file and everything worked fine. I then wanted to test downloading the .obb file from google play, so I used **monitor** to remove the .obb file from my device, not thinking that the file was still mounted at **/mnt/obb/!**

So I put the .obb file back, and `StorageManager.isObbMounted()` always returns true, but when I examine the directory (using a File object created with `StorageManager.getMountedObbPath()`), it's always empty.

I think the mount point is corrupted because I removed the .obb file while it was mounted. I'd like to '**umount /mnt/obb/**' to get back to a clean state, but I always get 'failed: Operation not permitted'.

How can I clean up the mess I made?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the device fixed the issue.